# Ruby test doesn't Increment User count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, functional-testing

I'm new to Ruby and I'm trying to create a test that will create a new user. I'm using devise and my test_helper.rb looks like:

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
# Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
   fixtures :all
# Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
end

class ActionController::TestCase
   include Devise::TestHelpers

  def sign_in_user
    @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
    sign_in users(:user1)
  end
end
```

My User Fixture looks like:

```
user1:
  id: 1
  email: user1@test.com
  encrypted_password: abcdef1
  role: Sales
  created_at: <%= Time.now %>
```

My Test is very simple:

```
require 'test_helper'
class UsersControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  setup do
    @controller = UsersController.new
    sign_in_user
  end

  test "should create user" do
    assert_difference('User.count') do
      post :create, user: {name: "Test", password: "Troll", password_confirmation: "Troll", email: "test@test.com", role: "Sales"}
    end

    assert_redirected_to user_path(assigns(:user))
  end
end
```

But whenever I run rake test, I always get the error that User.count didn't increase by 1 (expected 2 but was 1). What am I doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In your controller code - why don't you check your logs and/or add some puts statements such as "puts params.inspect"  and add "puts @use.inspect" (after it tries to create the user) to see what's really coming through to your controller. It's probably failing some validation due to the input being not what it expects or something...

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Do I just add puts params.inspect into the def create portion of User.rb? Unfortunately I did not write the code for User Controller (I'm only testing) so I don't really understand whats going on. Here is the code for User Controller: 
'@user = User.new(user_params)....
if user.save....
 flash[:success] = "User created"....
 redirect_to @user....
else....
 render 'new'....
end'

Comment: code formatting in comments is awful - edit your question and add the code there... and yes - add some puts statements into the `def create` method in the controller... you can always remove them later, but for now it will spit out some helpful data while you run the test.

Comment: @VEL, would you mind posting your whole source code for *app/models/user.rb*?

Comment: Could you also provide your *db/schema.rb*, please?